# Jar mismatch scenario

Tags: android

I'm encountering a lot of jar mismatch errors lately and I'd like to avoid them in the future.
So, here's my question: suppose I have an app that uses 2 library projects, both of which use the v4 support library jar. In total, I have 3 jar files. What can I do to avoid the jar mismatch error?

All I've read so far is the case where you have a project and a single library project. In this case, I think your supposed to delete the jar file in the project and keep the one in the library project.

Comment: can you be more specific what error you are encountering exactly?

Comment: "I think your supposed to delete the jar file in the project and keep the one in the library project". So what happens when you delete the jar form your project? Does it work or not work?

Comment: replace the other two jar files with any one of the jar file

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common if your project references several libraries, and each library references the same other library.

An example of this, your app is referencing the android support library v4, and you have 2 libraries which are also referencing the support library v4.

If you update your apps reference to the support library, but you don't update the support library v4 in your other libraries you will see this error.

The best thing is on each referenced library and your app, right click on the project > android tools > add support library. This will get the latest version and you should no longer see these errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing mismatch issue then simply copy one of them and paste in remaining libraries. E.g. as you've 3 v4 support library jars then copy one of them and paste at place of remaining two jars.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to understood by my example I used Map and Facebook in My project now Facebook,Map and my project have Android support jar so i removed Android Support jar from Facebook,My project but remain jar on Map,now i'm addded Android-Map-Extension as library project on Facebook And finally add Facebook library project on My project .....
```